# Name of resistor roles in circuits

Tags: resistors

I don't have a formal education in Electronic Engineering, and after some reading, I learned that a resistor could have different roles in a circuit. The roles I've learned so far are the following:

- Current Limiting Resistor
- Pull Up Resistor
- Pull Down Resistor
- Voltage Divider Resistors

What are the rest of a resistor roles categories? Is the term "Role" correct for this context? Where canI read more aboy resistir roles in circuits?

Comment: "Timing setting," "frequency setting," "gain setting," "temperature stabilizing," "global or local negative feedback," "quiescent voltage setting," "quiescent current setting," "voltage setting," "grid leak," "input protection,"  ... The number of ways that (roles by which) resistors are used is limited only by the range of your own imagination. The broader the scope by which you can imagine circuits, the more ways you can see that resistors play a role. Your answer will be found by expanding your ability to "see," and you will eventually realize that there are still more ways you haven't yet.

Comment: The fundamental operation of a resistor, that of defining a ratio between a current and a voltage, can be used in many ways, especially when  used in combination with other resistors, and other components. Two resistors can define a ratio. A resistor and capacitor can define a time.

Comment: @jonk, I am more interested in Digital Circuits. Does that simplify the list?

Comment: @AllanXu It does, of course. If you limit the scope of your imagination, then this (obviously) limits the range of your allowed imagination. Perhaps you might add this to your question to limit its scope.